# How to stream cloudfront real time logs to cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I need to monitor the CloudFront real time logs in cloud watch. Is there any way to stream CloudFront real time logs to the cloudwatch?

I know how to stream CloudFront standard(access)logs to cloudwatch(But it won't stream live logs and there will be a huge delay between live log time and log streaming time. so I won't prefer it) and how to stream real time logs to AWS OpenSearch through kinesis firehouse.

But in our project, we stream all service logs to the cloudwatch. So it would be better if any way to stream CloudFront logs to the cloudwatch.
Is there any possibility to do as my request?

Answer (score 0):

Barring any unannounced product that will stream CloudFront to CloudWatch (talk to your AWS account manager), you will need to write a Lambda to do this.

Configure CloudFront to write to Kinesis, and then [attach a Lambda function to that Kinesis stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html).

Where things will get tricky is that you may have multiple Lambdas running concurrently, reading from different shards in the Kinesis stream. If you attempt to write to the same log stream, you will need to retrieve the latest [sequence token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutLogEvents.html#CWL-PutLogEvents-request-sequenceToken) before calling `PutLogEvents`, and be prepared for (1) collisions, and (2) running up against quotas for writing to log streams.

Instead, I recommend that the first call to a handler Lambda create a new log stream, and subsequent calls to that Lambda write to that stream using the sequence token from the previous request. This may result in a lot of log streams, which may be challenging to read in real-time (although CloudWatch Logs Insights helps there).